# How to manipulate username before signin in Symfony2 FOSUserBundle?

Tags: php, symfony, fosuserbundle

I have symfony2 web app (with FOSUserBundle) I want to add a string `@something` before authentication. For example user want to login by his username `myusername` but the real username in database is `myusername@something`, so I have to add the `@something` before authentication process. I checked checkAction (I thought I could manipulate posted username there) but this method throws an execption:

```
throw new \RuntimeException('You must configure the check path to be handled by the firewall using form_login in your security firewall configuration.');
```

Where can I change the username after form post?

Comment: Maybe you can edit the User class´s getUserName to return only the part without "@.."

Comment: There might be `myusername@something` and `myusername@somethingelse`.

Comment: wouldnt be a problem, just get the index of "@" in the string and return a substring from zero to position of "@" -- anyway i dont know if thats clean because you would edit sth. in vendor/ directory which might get overwritten on update

Comment: Can you paste the `providers` section of your `security.yml` as well as the `fos_user` definitions in your `config.yml`?

Answer (score 0):

You can override the ProfileFormType to add an event listener to the form.
Before the submission occurs this will modify the data and append the `@something` suffix
if it hasn't been provided already by the user.

```
<?php

namespace Acme\UserBundle\Form\Type;

use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use FOS\UserBundle\Form\Type\ProfileFormType as BaseType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormEvent;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormEvents;

class ProfileFormType extends BaseType
{
    const USERNAME_SUFFIX = '@something';

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        parent::buildForm($builder, $options);

        $builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SUBMIT, function (FormEvent $event) {
            $data = $event->getData();

            if (isset($data['username']) && $this->usernameHasSuffix($data['username']) {
                $data['username'] = $data['username'].self::USERNAME_SUFFIX;
            }

            $event->setData($data);
        });
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'acme_user_profile';
    }

    private function usernameHasSuffix($username)
    {
        return substr($username, -strlen(self::USERNAME_SUFFIX)) === self::USERNAME_SUFFIX;
    }
}
```

Once created, just register it and tag it in the service container

```
# src/Acme/UserBundle/Resources/config/services.yml
services:
    acme_user.profile.form.type:
        class: Acme\UserBundle\Form\Type\ProfileFormType
        arguments: [%fos_user.model.user.class%]
        tags:
            - { name: form.type, alias: acme_user_profile }
```

Then reconfigure the FOS UserBundle to use this form.

```
# app/config/config.yml
fos_user:
    # ...
    profile:
        form:
            type: acme_user_profile
```